# Fail2ban unable to write iptables rules

Tags: centos6, fail2ban

Working on Centos 6.3 ,fail2ban version 0.9.6,  fail2ban is unable to write in iptables rules after start and nothing relating to f2b chain seen in iptables -L, I have configured it on local VM and it works like a charm, however on this server, it generates logs which are making me go crazy for 2 days now, Please see logs, seems to me as if it is unable to write rules in iptables, wonder how to fix this :O 
P.S Jails have been tested and verified.
Any help in this regard will be so grateful.
Thanks in advance

*iptables -L*

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

*service fail2ban status*

```
fail2ban-server (pid  30663) is running...
Status
|- Number of jail:      2
`- Jail list:   opensips, ssh-iptables
```

***fail2ban Logs***

```
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.server[21215]: INFO Changed logging target to SYSLOG (/dev/log) for Fail2ban v0.9.6
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.database[21215]: INFO Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Creating new jail 'ssh-iptables'
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Jail 'ssh-iptables' uses pyinotify {}
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Added logfile = /var/log/secure
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set maxRetry = 2
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.actions[21215]: INFO Set banTime = 60
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set findtime = 600
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set maxlines = 10
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.server[21215]: INFO Jail ssh-iptables is not a JournalFilter instance
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Creating new jail 'opensips'
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Jail 'opensips' uses pyinotify {}
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Added logfile = /var/log/messages
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set maxRetry = 2
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.actions[21215]: INFO Set banTime = 60
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.filter[21215]: INFO Set findtime = 600
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Jail 'ssh-iptables' started
Feb 20 19:14:05 server-1 fail2ban.jail[21215]: INFO Jail 'opensips' started
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-SSH#012iptables  -A f2b-SSH -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-SSH -- stdout: ''
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-SSH#012iptables  -A f2b-SSH -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-SSH -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\niptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\niptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\n"
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-SSH#012iptables  -A f2b-SSH -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-SSH -- returned 3
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.actions[21215]: ERROR Failed to start jail 'ssh-iptables' action 'iptables-allports': Error starting action
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-opensips#012iptables  -A f2b-opensips -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p all -j f2b-opensips -- stdout: ''
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-opensips#012iptables  -A f2b-opensips -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p all -j f2b-opensips -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\niptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\niptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.\n"
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.action[21215]: ERROR iptables  -N f2b-opensips#012iptables  -A f2b-opensips -j RETURN#012iptables  -I INPUT -p all -j f2b-opensips -- returned 3
Feb 20 19:14:06 server-1 fail2ban.actions[21215]: ERROR Failed to start jail 'opensips' action 'iptables-allports': Error starting action
```

Comment: Is the server an OpenVZ container?

Comment: Its a physical machine

Comment: This line also appears in the log now:
<27>fail2ban.CommandAction[17242]: ERROR Invariant check failed. Trying to restore a sane environment

Comment: Update the system.

Comment: The issue is solved by changing python version, no need to update the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in python version..
I edited /usr/bin/fail2ban-client and /usr/bin/fail2ban-server with correct path("whereis python" gives you paths) in the top line as

## !/usr/bin/python2.6 -Es

which was previously

## !/usr/bin/python -Es (older version of python),

Due to this older version's compilation, fail2ban was unable to write iptables rules.
Started fail2ban using command:
fail2ban-client start

Now it is running and blocking unwanted IP's